# make CMB text_datetime_timestamp field repeatable

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm using CMB to creat custom fields for  wordpress custom post
https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

I'm using text_datetime_timestamp to set date and time and I need to make this field repeatable which is not

as I go through the documentation we can make new fields but I can't figure out how it make "text_datetime_timestamp" field repeatable

any body can show me the way to accomplish that ?

thank you

Comment: ??? https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#common-field-parameters

Comment: text_datetime_timestamp not repeatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution to make the field repeatable so I put the field inside group and made it repeatable

```
array(
            'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_date_group',
            'type'        => 'group',
            'description' => '',
            'options'     => array(
                'group_title'   => __( 'Date/Time {#}', 'cmb' ), 
                'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Date/Time', 'cmb' ),
                'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Date/Time', 'cmb' ),
                'sortable'      => true, // beta
            ),
            'fields'      => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Date/Time',
                    'desc' => '',
                    'id' => $prefix . 'course_date',
                    'type' => 'text_datetime_timestamp'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

I hope this answer will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

Well here is my code, you may try this

```
$cmb= new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id' => $prefix.'testing',
    'title' => _('Testing'),
    'object_types' => array('post'),
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true,
    ));

$cmb->add_field( array(
'name' => 'Test Date/Time Picker Combo (UNIX timestamp)',
'id'   => 'wiki_test_datetime_timestamp',
'type' => 'text_datetime_timestamp',
'repeatable' => true,
```

) );